# Vim advanced substitution

Tags: vim, editing

I've done a lot of complex edits and also used sed a lot in the past, but this is something that I can't quite figure out how to do.  I know how to use beginning and end of line (`^$`), and wildcards (`.*$`), and even throwing in `CRs`, but this is columnar.  I have the following lines:

```
!********************************************************************************
!                                                                               *
! Processing Overview:                                                          *
!                                                                               *
!     begin-setup                                                               *
!     begin-heading        *
!     begin-footing        *
!     begin-report        *
!          Strd-begin-Program       *
!          STRD-Print-Lis       *
!          Prompt-Parameters                                                    *
!          Feedback-Value-Update                                                *
```

I need to move the asterisk to column 81 on all lines for uniformity and readability.  Anyone know how to do that?
TIA,
David

Comment: Use Visual Block mode. See the procedure here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/align-a-block-of-code-on-the-basis-of-a-single-character/20670#20670. You'll have to adapt it for your exact use case, but it's a useful technique to learn.

Comment: Good stuff.  I've never investigated visual block mode until now (I'm old school, hahaha), but I'll be adding this to the toolbox, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be something like

```
%norm $x80|p
```

Breakdown

```
%             operate on the entire buffer
norm          following normal command
$             go to end of the line
x             delete the character
80|           goto column 80
p             paste
```

Note that virtual edit needs to be set. I have following entry in my `_vimrc`

```
 set ve=all
```

Comment: Wow!  I've used sed before for consecutive commands, but I didn't know about norm and 80|.  I used to tell people that I was the king of vi, a viking, but I pass my crown to Lieven.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, a follow up question.  Since all my lines aren't this kind of comment, I wanted to search for * at the end of the line.  This was my attempt: %norm /*$x80|p
Never mind, I found it.  :-)  %norm /*$<CR>x80|p

Comment: fwiw - I would have answered `g/*$/norm $x80|p`but you already got a solution so, well done!